# What is the function of でも in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

さっき丁寧体で紹介した「いや」この「いや」は普通体でもよく使います。

What is the function of でも here?

Comment: Can you explain why you have a question about でも?  For example, tell us what you think it means, then take some time to explain why you are confused/unsure about your translation.  If you do this, your questions will be more likely to receive up-votes.

Answer (score 3):

> さっき 丁寧体 で 紹介 し た 「いや」 この 「いや」 は 普通 体 で よく 使い ます
>
> さっき 丁寧体 で 紹介 し た 「いや」 この 「いや」 は 普通 体 で *も* よく 使い ます

These two sentences express almost the same meaning.

However, in the latter sentence, we emphasize 「普通体」 than the former sentence by using 「も」.

---

In this context, 「も」 is called とりたて助詞(focus particle).

To quote from [とりたて助詞の機能と解釈](http://www.f.waseda.jp/harada/documents/ircjs-1995.pdf)

> The basic semantic function of 'toritate'(designting)-particles in
> Japanese, which correspond to so-called 'focus particles' in English,
> is to designate an ob ject in the context as the focused element, and
> to quantify the set of its alternatives (contrastive objects).

We can form とりたて-form by appending 「は」 or 「も」 after another case particle (格助詞).

> このゲームはアメリカで遊べます。このゲームは日本で *も* 遊べます。
>
> We can play this game in America. We can play this game even in Japan.

Here, we append the focus particle 「も」 after the case particle 「で」 to emphasize “even in Japan”.

> このゲームはアメリカでは遊べません。このゲームは日本で *は* 遊べます。
>
> We cannot play this game in America. But we can play this game in Japan.

Here, we append the focus particle 「は」 after the case particle 「で」  to emphasize  “but in Japan”.

Answer (score 2):

Here, でも is used to show contrast, and it could be roughly translated as "even" in English. I think it's the most common usage of でも.

> この「いや」は普通体でもよく使います。
> This 「いや」is used often, **even** in normal style.

If you are familiar with the grammar い-adjective + くても 〜 , you can think of this as the noun/な-adjective version of the same grammar point, and the meaning will become easier to grasp:

い-adj (drop い) +くても 〜

> 寒く**ても**、ジャケットを着ないで出かけた。**Even** though it was cold, I went out without wearing a jacket.

Noun (or な-adj) + でも 〜

> 雨**でも**、傘を持たないで出かけた。**Despite** the rain, I went out without an umbrella.
>
> 普通体**でも**よく使います。 **Even** in the normal style, it is often used. / **Even though** [it is] normal style, it is often used.

---

Edit: after giving it a second read, I think there's another way to look at this sentence. The combination of the particles で (by means of, with) and も (also) :

> 「いや」は丁寧体**で** 使います。We use 「いや」**with** the polite style.
>
> 「いや」は普通体**で** 使います。We use 「いや」**with** the normal style.
>
> 「いや」は丁寧体**で** 使います。普通体 **でも** 使います。We use 「いや」 **with** the polite style. We **also** use it **with** the normal style.

In my opinion, both interpretations make sense and there are many cases where they overlap. Ultimately, the meaning   of the sentence is also determined by the context.